# Pullback of etale cover along itself

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-geometry

I would like know if there's anything wrong with the following proof.

**Claim**. Let $f : X \rightarrow S$ be a finite etale of degree $n$. Then there is a noncanonical isomorphism $f^*X \cong \amalg_n X$.

Proof by induction on $n$. For $n = 1$, a finite etale morphism of degree 1 must be an isomorphism $S \rightarrow S$, so we are done. For the induction step, assume the claim for all etale morphisms of degree $n-1 \ge 1$ and let $f : X \rightarrow S$ be finite etale of degree $n$. The diagonal $X \rightarrow f^* X$ is a clopen immersion that splits off a component isomorphic to $X$, hence $f^* X \cong X \amalg X'$ where $X' \rightarrow X$ is a finite etale morphism of degree $n-1$. By induction hypothesis we are done.

The above proof is a slight alteration of the proof of Stacks Project Lemma 40.18.3, which claims that there IS a trivializing etale cover for $X$. I was surprised that I couldn't find a single source that remarks that we can just take the trivializing cover to be $X$ itself. Is there something wrong with my claim?

Comment: But you didn't prove that $f^*X\simeq\coprod_n X$ in your induction process, only that $f^*X\simeq X\coprod X'$ and that *after pulling back along $X'\to X$* you get something completely split. The thing is, you claim holds in particular for Galois covering, but not in general. For example, let $k=\mathbb{Q}$ and $L=k[x]/(x^3-2)$. Then $L\otimes_k L=L[t]/(t^3-2)=L[t]/((t-x)(t^2-tx+x^2)=L\times L[t]/(t^2-tx+x^2)$. But the second factor does not split.

Comment: @Roland This look like an answer to me. Care to submit it as such?